# Autosys file watcher file regex

Tags: shell, unix, autosys

I have been facing issue in identifying similar file name in my file watcher service. My files looks like this:

```
1. filename1.YYYYMMDD.txt.YYYYMMDDSSSSSS.END regex I am using filename1.*.txt.*.END 
2. filename1.YYYYMMDD_trl.txt.YYYYMMDDSSSSSS.END regex  I am using filename1.*_trl.*.END
3. filename2.YYYYMMDD.txt.YYYYMMDDSSSSSS.END regex  I am using filename2.*.txt.*.END
4. filename2.YYYYMMDD_trl.txt.YYYYMMDDSSSSSS.END regex  I am using filename2.*_trl.*.END
```

So you see the problem here, 1 get confused with 2 and 3 gets confused with 4.
What should I do, to make it more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for regex i would show this by `grep`.
However, `ls` command doesn't support regex.

Sample file:

```
$ cat filenames                                                                                                           
filename1.20210225.txt.20210225123456.END                                                                                                 
filename1.20200225_trl.txt.20210225123456.END
```

Code:

```
$ egrep "filename1.([0-9]{8}).txt.([0-9]{14}).END" filenames                                                              
filename1.20210225.txt.20210225123456.END                                                                                                 
$ egrep "filename1.([0-9]{8})_trl.txt.([0-9]{14}).END" filenames                                                          
filename1.20200225_trl.txt.20210225123456.END
```

Explanation:

in `egrep "filename1.([0-9]{8}).txt.([0-9]{14}).END" filenames`

`[0-9]` - Any digits from 0123456789

`{8}` - Exact count of characters. YYYYMMDD is of 8 characters similarly YYYYMMDDSSSSSS - 14

Comment: This is not working. Autosys doesnt indentify [0-9]

Comment: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/31701/how-to-support-regular-expressions-with.html